# HttpResponseText Return some Licence issue

Tags: xmlhttprequest, rational-team-concert, oslc

In below code "`Http.ResponseText`" returns Some License issue.
Please let me know the solution:

[image: popup error]

```
Public Function GetServicebyProjectName (http, url, projectName)

    Dim text
    Dim doc
    Dim xmldoc
    Dim element, elements


'http.Open "GET", url&"/rootservices", False

    ' Since Rational Team Concert workitem catalog service is fixed, skip rootservice 
    ' checking. 
    http.Open "GET", url&"/oslc/workitems/catalog.xml", False
    http.Send

    Set doc = http.ResponseXML

    Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    xmldoc.loadXML(Http.ResponseText)

    'Obtain list of services from service provider for input project.
    set elements = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("oslc_disc:ServiceProvider")

    For each element in elements
        If element.text = projectName Then

            set services = element.getElementsByTagName("oslc_disc:services")
            For each service in services

                ' Parse service XML structure to get "rdf.resouce"
                ' Attribute(0) is the resource value.
                service_url = service.attributes(0).nodeValue

            Next

        End If
    Next

    GetServicebyProjectName = service_url

End Function
```

The popup error is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> Licensed Materials - Property of IBM (c) Copyright IBM Corporation 2005, 2015. All Rights Reserved. 
Note to U.S. Government Users Restricted Rights: Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. 
<html > <head> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"> <title> </title> 
<link type="tect/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ccm/web/_style/?include=A—&etag=DNUG8pOy1Eg_en_US&_proxyURL= %2Fccm&ss=K7RWd"> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ccm/web/netjazz.ajailjazz.ico"> 
< style type="tect/css"> #net-jazz-ajax-NoScriptMessage { width: 100%; color: #000000; font-size gem; text-align: center; position: absolute top: 1%; z-index: 999; 
</style> 
</head> 
<body class="claro"> <noscript> <div id="net-jazz-ajax-NoScriptMessage">lavascript is either disabled or not available in your Browser</div> </noscript> <div id="net-jazz-ajax-InitialLoadMessage"> Loading...</div>
```

for reference:

```
Public Function JazzLogin(url, userid, password)

    Dim jazzUserid
    Dim JazzPassword

    JazzUserid = "j_username=jazzadmin"
    JazzPassword = "j_password=jazzadmin"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

    ' login to jazz server specified in the parameter section.
    http.Open "GET", url&"/authenticated/identity", False
    http.Send

    http.Open "POST", url&"/authenticated/j_security_check", False
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    http.Send JazzUserid&"&"&JazzPassword

    Set JazzLogin = http


End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "licence issue".
The license is simply part of the header of the HTML page returned by your query.
The actual message in that HTML page is:

```
Javascript is either disabled or not available in your Browser
```

As [seen here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/236375/javascript-is-either-disabled-or-not-available-in-your-browser), this is a symptom of a lack of authentication. Or your authentication function did not fully work.